I'm curious about the role of the 'host' in the Spring Cloud Gateway YAML configuration
I am currently a university student in Korea. I am studying Spring Cloud Gateway and am curious about the reason for specifying the host in the YAML configuration and writing the same host information in the filter. Additionally, I would like to know the purpose of using the host.
Currently applied YML files
spring:
     application:
     name: spring-cloud-gateway-sample-study
     cloud:
        gateway:
          routes:
            - id: rewrite_request_upper
              uri: lb://first-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/first-service/**
            - Host=*.rewriterequestupper.org
          filters:
            - PrefixPath=/httpbin
            - AddResponseHeader=X-TestHeader, rewrite_request_upper
            - ModifyRequestBody= String, String, {function}

Currently applied code
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {

    return builder.routes().route("rewrite_request_upper", r -> r
                        .host("*.rewriterequestupper.org")
                        .and()
                        .path("/first-service/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.prefixPath("/message")
                                .addResponseHeader("X-TestHeader", "rewrite_request_upper")
                                .modifyRequestBody(String.class, String.class, (exchange, s) 
                                -> Mono.just(s.toUpperCase() + s.toUpperCase()))
                        ).uri(URL))

I have left this message because, although there are no issues with the results, I am curious about the host.
